# TensorFlow initializing Tensor of ones

Tags: python, tensorflow

So suppose I have a tensor

```
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 5])
```

So that I know the number of columns but not the number of rows. I need to initialize a vector of ones of dimension `nrows x 1`

Now the following block of code does not work,

```
o = tf.ones(shape=(tf.shape(X)[0], 1))
==> TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

Nor does,

```
o = tf.ones(shape=(X.get_shape()[0].value, 1))
==> TypeError: Input 'dims' of 'Fill' Op has type 
    string that does not match expected type of int32.
```

Now, I have found that one way to get around this is to actually make my vector of ones a placeholder,

```
o = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
```

And to pass in a numpy array of ones of appropriate size in my `feed_dict`. But this solution strikes me as inelegant and not the intended use of a placeholder. I could be wrong here, but surely there's a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to solve your problem is to use tf.pack operation:

`o = tf.ones(shape=tf.pack([tf.shape(X)[0], 1]))`

The reason you had errors is that TensorFlow shape is expected to be a list of integers or a tensor [link](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/constant_op.md#ones). tf.pack makes it easy to convert a list of integers and/or TensorFlow scalars into a Tensor object.

Comment: tf.pack is no longer supported by `tensorflow>=1.00`

Comment: You can use `stack` though I think?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
0 * tf.identity(X) + 1
```