# How to get the dimensions of a tensor (in TensorFlow) at graph construction time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

I am trying an Op that is not behaving as expected.

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[128, 2])
  embeddings = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([50000, 64], -1.0, 1.0))
  embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)
  embed = tf.reduce_sum(embed, reduction_indices=0)
```

So I need to know the dimensions of the Tensor `embed`. I know that it can be done at the run time but it's too much work for such a simple operation. What's the easier way to do it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`Tensor.get_shape()` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079787/tensor-with-unspecified-dimension-in-tensorflow).

[From documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor.get_shape):

```
c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
print(c.get_shape())
==> TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(3)])
```

Comment: If anyone wonders: `tf.shape(c)` returns a 1-D integer tensor representing the shape of `c`. In the example given in this answer,  `tf.shape(c)` returns `Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)`

Comment: @nobar if the dimension is `None` (i.e., if it is unspecified), you might need to use `tf.shape(c)`. For example, if `a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None,2))`, and you run `tf.Session().run(tf.constant(a.get_shape().as_list()[0]), {a:[[1,2]]})
` you will get error, but you can get the dimension by: `tf.Session().run(tf.shape(a)[0], {a:[[1,2]]})`.

Answer (score 64):

I see most people confused about `tf.shape(tensor)` and `tensor.get_shape()`
Let's make it clear:

1. `tf.shape`

`tf.shape` is used for dynamic shape. If your tensor's shape is **changable**, use it. 
An example: a input is an image with changable width and height, we want resize it to half of its size, then we can write something like:
`new_height = tf.shape(image)[0] / 2`

2. `tensor.get_shape`

`tensor.get_shape` is used for fixed shapes, which means the tensor's **shape can be deduced** in the graph.

Conclusion:
`tf.shape` can be used almost anywhere, but `t.get_shape` only for shapes can be deduced from graph.

Answer (score 13):

A function to *access* the values:

```
def shape(tensor):
    s = tensor.get_shape()
    return tuple([s[i].value for i in range(0, len(s))])
```

Example:

```
batch_size, num_feats = shape(logits)
```

Comment: `return tuple(tensor.get_shape().as_list())` if you want a tuple, or directly return the python list as in `return tensor.get_shape().as_list()`

Answer (score 5):

Just print out the embed after construction graph (ops) without running:

```
import tensorflow as tf

...

train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[128, 2])
embeddings = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([50000, 64], -1.0, 1.0))
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)
print (embed)
```

This will show the shape of the embed tensor:

```
Tensor("embedding_lookup:0", shape=(128, 2, 64), dtype=float32)
```

Usually, it's good to check shapes of all tensors before training your models.

Comment: While the answer I gave before you post yours was correct, your answer gives more information about the tensor than just its shape, hence, I accept it as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Let's make it simple as hell. If you want a single number for the number of dimensions like `2, 3, 4, etc.,` then just use `tf.rank()`. But, if you want the exact shape of the tensor then use `tensor.get_shape()`

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
   arr = tf.random_normal(shape=(10, 32, 32, 128))
   a = tf.random_gamma(shape=(3, 3, 1), alpha=0.1)
   print(sess.run([tf.rank(arr), tf.rank(a)]))
   print(arr.get_shape(), ", ", a.get_shape())     


# for tf.rank()    
[4, 3]

# for tf.get_shape()
Output: (10, 32, 32, 128) , (3, 3, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The method tf.shape is a TensorFlow static method. However, there is also the method get_shape for the Tensor class. See

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#get_shape

Comment: None really - I was just trying to explain it as succinctly as possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To create tensor in tensorflow using tf.constant()

This is to import the library

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

This will create the tensor

```
tensor = tf.constant([[[2,4,5], [5,6,6]], [[9,7,8], [4,8,2]], [[7,1,3], [4,8,9]]])
```

This will show the tensor

`tensor`

this will show the number of dimension

```
tensor.ndim
```

Answer (score 0):

#create a tensor

```
tensor = tf.constant([[[1, 2, 3],
                   [3, 4, 5]],
                  [[5, 6, 7],
                   [8, 6, 9]],
                  [[2, 1, 5],
                   [5, 7, 8]]])
tensor
```

#Display result

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy= array([[[1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 5]],

   [[5, 6, 7],
    [8, 6, 9]],

   [[2, 1, 5],
    [5, 7, 8]]], dtype=int32)>
```