# tf.shape() get wrong shape in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

I define a tensor like this:

`x = tf.get_variable("x", [100])`

But when I try to print shape of tensor :

`print( tf.shape(x) )`

I get **Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)**, why the result of output should not be shape=(100)

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41771268/1358091) answer very useful to analyze the shape of a tensor, despite it is not the accepted one.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

[tf.shape(input, name=None)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) returns a 1-D integer tensor representing the shape of input.

You're looking for: `x.get_shape()` that returns the `TensorShape` of the `x` variable.

Update: I wrote an article to clarify the dynamic/static shapes in Tensorflow because of this answer: https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/2018/07/28/understanding-tensorflow-tensors-shape-static-dynamic/

Comment: `x.get_shape().as_list()` is an often used form to convert the shape to a standard python list. Added here for reference.

Answer (score 13):

Clarification:

tf.shape(x) creates an op and returns an object which stands for the output of the constructed op, which is what you are printing currently. To get the shape, run the operation in a session:

```
matA = tf.constant([[7, 8], [9, 10]])
shapeOp = tf.shape(matA) 
print(shapeOp) #Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(shapeOp)) #[2 2]
```

credit: After looking at the above answer, I saw the answer to [tf.rank function in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195549/tf-rank-function-in-tensorflow) which I found more helpful and I have tried rephrasing it here.

Answer (score 12):

Just a quick example, to make things clear:

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(2, 3, 4)))
print('-'*60)
print("v1", tf.shape(a))
print('-'*60)
print("v2", a.get_shape())
print('-'*60)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print("v3", sess.run(tf.shape(a)))
print('-'*60)
print("v4",a.shape)
```

Output will be:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
v1 Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
------------------------------------------------------------
v2 (2, 3, 4)
------------------------------------------------------------
v3 [2 3 4]
------------------------------------------------------------
v4 (2, 3, 4)
```

Also this should be helpful:
[How to understand static shape and dynamic shape in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096225/how-to-understand-static-shape-and-dynamic-shape-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 5):

Similar question is nicely explained in [TF FAQ](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq#tensor_shapes):

> In TensorFlow, a tensor has both a static (inferred) shape and a
>   dynamic (true) shape. The static shape can be read using the
>   `tf.Tensor.get_shape` method: this shape is inferred from the operations
>   that were used to create the tensor, and may be partially complete. If
>   the static shape is not fully defined, the dynamic shape of a Tensor t
>   can be determined by evaluating `tf.shape(t)`.

So [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) returns you a tensor, will always have a size of `shape=(N,)`, and can be calculated in a session:

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(2, 3, 4)))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(tf.shape(a))
```

On the other hand you can extract the static shape by using `x.get_shape().as_list()` and this can be calculated anywhere.

Comment: What is `shape=(N,)` represent? Can you show example when static shape and dinamic shape differs?

Comment: @mrgloom shape=(n,) represents a vector of size n. It is not easy to show such an example because you need to confuse TF enough to lose control of the shape

Answer (score 2):

Simply, use `tensor.shape` to get the *static shape*:

```
In [102]: a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128])

# returns [None, 128]
In [103]: a.shape.as_list()
Out[103]: [None, 128]
```

Whereas to get the *dynamic shape*, use `tf.shape()`:

```
dynamic_shape = tf.shape(a)
```

---

You can also get the shape as you'd in NumPy with `your_tensor.shape` as in the following example.

```
In [11]: tensr = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])

In [12]: tensr.shape
Out[12]: TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(5)])

In [13]: list(tensr.shape)
Out[13]: [Dimension(2), Dimension(5)]

In [16]: print(tensr.shape)
(2, 5)
```

---

Also, this example, for tensors which can be `eval`uated.

```
In [33]: tf.shape(tensr).eval().tolist()
Out[33]: [2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tensorflow 2.0 Compatible Answer**: **`Tensorflow 2.x (>= 2.0)`** compatible answer for nessuno's solution is shown below:

```
x = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("x", [100])

print(x.get_shape())
```