# How to get Tensorflow tensor dimensions (shape) as int values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Suppose I have a Tensorflow tensor. How do I get the dimensions (shape) of the tensor as integer values? I know there are two methods, `tensor.get_shape()` and `tf.shape(tensor)`, but I can't get the shape values as integer `int32` values.

For example, below I've created a 2-D tensor, and I need to get the number of rows and columns as `int32` so that I can call `reshape()` to create a tensor of shape `(num_rows * num_cols, 1)`. However, the method `tensor.get_shape()` returns values as `Dimension` type, not `int32`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()    
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[1001,1002,1003],[3,4,5]]), dtype=tf.float32)

sess.run(tensor)    
# array([[ 1001.,  1002.,  1003.],
#        [    3.,     4.,     5.]], dtype=float32)

tensor_shape = tensor.get_shape()    
tensor_shape
# TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(3)])    
print tensor_shape    
# (2, 3)

num_rows = tensor_shape[0] # ???
num_cols = tensor_shape[1] # ???

tensor2 = tf.reshape(tensor, (num_rows*num_cols, 1))    
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1750, in reshape
#     name=name)
#   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 454, in apply_op
#     as_ref=input_arg.is_ref)
#   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 621, in convert_to_tensor
#     ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
#   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 180, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
#     return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
#   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 163, in constant
#     tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape))
#   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 353, in make_tensor_proto
#     _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
#   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 290, in _AssertCompatible
#     (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
# TypeError: Expected int32, got Dimension(6) of type 'Dimension' instead.
```

Answer (score 146, accepted):

To get the shape as a list of ints, do `tensor.get_shape().as_list()`.

To complete your `tf.shape()` call, try `tensor2 = tf.reshape(tensor, tf.TensorShape([num_rows*num_cols, 1]))`. Or you can directly do `tensor2 = tf.reshape(tensor, tf.TensorShape([-1, 1]))` where its first dimension can be inferred.

Comment: Thanks, that lets me call and complete `tf.reshape()`, but I would really like to get `num_rows` and `num_cols` as integers for other operations.

Comment: Try `tensor.get_shape().as_list()`

Comment: For completeness, this code works: `num_rows, num_cols = x.get_shape().as_list()`

Comment: Nice!  I was using python int() to cast the results of x.get_shape(). ie num_rows=int(x.get_shape()[1]), num_cols=int(x.get_shape()[2]), etc.Yep, kinda a hacky to get around that pesky error, but it worked.  Thanks for enlightening me to a better way :-)

Comment: In TF2.0, it seems not work: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape

Comment: Can anyone say whether this also applies within custom loss functions? I get "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'as_list'" when I try to use within a loss function.

Answer (score 33):

Another way to solve this is like this:

```
tensor_shape[0].value
```

This will return the int value of the Dimension object.

Answer (score 13):

**2.0 Compatible Answer**: In **`Tensorflow 2.x (2.1)`**, you can get the dimensions (shape) of the tensor as integer values, as shown in the Code below:

**Method 1 (using `tf.shape`)**:

```
import tensorflow as tf
c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
Shape = c.shape.as_list()
print(Shape)   # [2,3]
```

**Method 2 (using `tf.get_shape()`)**:

```
import tensorflow as tf
c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
Shape = c.get_shape().as_list()
print(Shape)   # [2,3]
```

Comment: is there any difference between the two methods?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096395/11530462

Answer (score 8):

for a 2-D tensor, you can get the number of rows and columns as int32 using the following code:

```
rows, columns = map(lambda i: i.value, tensor.get_shape())
```

Comment: Very inelegant.  How does this add to the already provided answers?

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution is to use `map()` as follows:

```
tensor_shape = map(int, my_tensor.shape)
```

This converts all the `Dimension` objects to `int`

Answer (score 0):

In later versions (tested with TensorFlow 1.14) there's a more numpy-like way to get the shape of a tensor. You can use `tensor.shape` to get the shape of the tensor.

```
tensor_shape = tensor.shape
print(tensor_shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this line of code:

```
tensor_shape[0].value
```

It will give you the shape of the tensor formatted as an integer.