# Tensorflow c++: how to get the tensor shape of an `Output?`

Tags: c++, tensorflow

There's `TF_GraphGetTensorShape` in C API, but the interface isn't compatible with C++ `Graph` and `Output`. How to do the same using tensorflow C/C++ API?

For example. How to get the returned tensor shape of `Slice` operation using C++ API and then using that tensor shape to make a `variable` with the same shape?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is  a small function which returns the shape as a vector, e.g. {48,48,2}

```
std::vector<int> get_tensor_shape(tensorflow::Tensor& tensor)
{
    std::vector<int> shape;
    int num_dimensions = tensor.shape().dims()
    for(int ii_dim=0; ii_dim<num_dimensions; ii_dim++) {
        shape.push_back(tensor.shape().dim_size(ii_dim));
    }
    return shape;
}
```

Apart from that I found tensor.DebugString() helpful, which yields for example
"Tensor type: float shape: [48,48,2] values: [[0,0390625 -1][0,0390625]]...>"

For python see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40666375/2135504, where `tensor.get_shape().as_list()` is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

I have never used tensorflow C API but in C++ API you have `class Tensor` which have function `shape()`. It will return `const TensorShape&`, which has function `dim_size(int index)`. This function will return dimension for given index value. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: `tensor` only returns after session runs. If you need to get the tensor shape before running the session, you can use TF_GraphGetTensorShape in C api. I just don't know how to do this in C++ API. Something related is inferring the output tensor shape of some operation, which is either not provided by C++ API or I haven't found..

Comment: Sorry but I don't know the full context of your question, so I cannot really help you. As I understand you want to know dimensions of some Tensor, so you should have object of this class. Maybe you can add some example of code to your question

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`tensor_shape.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/edb4bc4662271d36d59540de1173d5464b9b9105/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.h#L302), it looks like `tensor.shape().dim_sizes()` should give you a vector containing the shape.