# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'int'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Hope you guys are in good health. Respected members I am working on Cifar10 dataset 
and getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'int'
I use same algorithm for mnist dataset(GreyScale) but their is no error. But now I am using same algorithm of tensorflow for training on Cifar10(rgb). Is this error occurs because of (rgb) dataset?I am sharing my code please have a look Thank you

**Code**

```
layer1_neuron=500
layer2_neuron=500
layer3_neuron=500
number_of_class=10
batch_size=200

    #my neural network   

def neural_network(x_train):
    hidden_layer_1={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3072,layer1_neuron])),
        'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer1_neuron]))
         }
    hidden_layer_2={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer1_neuron,layer2_neuron])),
        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer2_neuron]))
        }
    hidden_layer_3={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer2_neuron,layer3_neuron])),
        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer3_neuron]))
        }
    output={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer3_neuron,number_of_class])),
        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([number_of_class]))
        }

    l1=tf.add(tf.matmul(x_train,hidden_layer_1['weights']),hidden_layer_1['biases'])
    l1=tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2=tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_layer_2['weights']),hidden_layer_2['biases'])
    l2=tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3=tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_layer_3['weights']),hidden_layer_3['biases'])
    l3=tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output=tf.add(tf.matmul(l3,output['weights']),output['biases'])

    return output


    # for splitting out batches of data
class Dataset:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self._index_in_epoch = 0
        self._epochs_completed = 0
        self._data = data
        self._num_examples = data.shape[0]
        pass


    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

    def next_batch(self,batch_size,shuffle = True):
        start = self._index_in_epoch
        if start == 0 and self._epochs_completed == 0:
            idx = np.arange(0, self._num_examples)  # get all possible indexes
            np.random.shuffle(idx)  # shuffle indexe
            self._data = self.data[idx]  # get list of `num` random samples

    # go to the next batch
        if start + batch_size > self._num_examples:
            self._epochs_completed += 1
            rest_num_examples = self._num_examples - start
            data_rest_part = self.data[start:self._num_examples]
            idx0 = np.arange(0, self._num_examples)  # get all possible indexes
            np.random.shuffle(idx0)  # shuffle indexes
            self._data = self.data[idx0]  # get list of `num` random samples

            start = 0
            self._index_in_epoch = batch_size - rest_num_examples #avoid the case where the #sample != integar times of batch_size
            end =  self._index_in_epoch  
            data_new_part =  self._data[start:end]  
            return np.concatenate((data_rest_part, data_new_part), axis=0)
        else:
            self._index_in_epoch += batch_size
            end = self._index_in_epoch

            return self._data[start:end]


def traning_neuralNetwork(x_train,y_train):
    x=tf.placeholder('float',[None,3072])
    y=tf.placeholder('float')
    total_epochs=10
    total_loss=0
    epoch_loss=0
    batch_size=200
    num_batch = int(np.ceil(48000/batch_size))
    prediction=neural_network(x)
    cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=y))
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
    temp_x_train_next_batch=Dataset(x_train)
    temp_y_train_next_batch=Dataset(y_train)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range (total_epochs):

            total_loss=0
            for _ in range (num_batch):
                x_train=temp_x_train_next_batch.next_batch(batch_size)
                y_train=temp_y_train_next_batch.next_batch(batch_size)
                _,epoch_loss=sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict={x:x_train,y:y_train})
                total_loss+=epoch_loss
            print('Epoch ',epoch, " loss = ",total_loss)

        print("Traning Complete!")
        correct=tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
        accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,'float'))
        print('accuracy',accuracy.eval({x:x_test,y :y_test}))
```

**error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-aeb4ef85487e> in <module>()
----> 1 traning_neuralNetwork(x_train,y_train)

<ipython-input-26-7e54c20d2131> in traning_neuralNetwork(x_train, y_train)
    102             for _ in range (num_batch):
    103                 x_train=temp_x_train_next_batch.next_batch(batch_size)
--> 104                 y_train=temp_y_train_next_batch.next_batch(batch_size)
    105                 _,epoch_loss=sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict={x:x_train,y:y_train})
    106                 total_loss+=epoch_loss

<ipython-input-26-7e54c20d2131> in next_batch(self, batch_size, shuffle)
     57         start = self._index_in_epoch
     58         if start == 0 and self._epochs_completed == 0:
---> 59             idx = np.arange(0, self._num_examples)  # get all possible indexes
     60             np.random.shuffle(idx)  # shuffle indexe
     61             self._data = self.data[idx]  # get list of `num` random samples

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'int'
```

Comment: `data.shape[0]` returns a `Dimension` object. You should try to cast it to integer. Try for example `int(data.shape[0])`

Comment: Now their is slicing problem  please see the error below

**Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice_400' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [49000,10], [1,49000], [1,49000], [1].**

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666316/how-to-get-tensorflow-tensor-dimensions-shape-as-int-values) will help you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe tensor not a value that can be calculated, so I guess adding `.numpy()` to the end of the tensor might work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is that you have previously manipulated your data sets in numpy formats, but now are using tensorflow foormats such as `tf.Variable` or `tf.Tensor`.

This line

```
self._num_examples = data.shape[0]
```

returns an `int` if data is a numpy array:

```
np_data = np.random.randn(10,10)
np_ans = np_data.shape[0]
print(type(np_ans))

>>> <class 'int'>
```

but if data is a tf.Variable :

```
tf_data = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(10,10), dtype=tf.float32)
tf_ans = tf_data.shape[0]
print(type(tf_ans))

>>> <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape.Dimension'>
```

an instance of `tensor_shape.Dimension` is returned which can then not be used by `np.arrange()` here:

```
---> 59             idx = np.arange(0, self._num_examples)
```

because `np.arrange()` requires `int` arguments.

As a quick fix, try swapping

```
self._num_examples = data.shape[0]
```

to

```
self._num_examples = data.shape[0].value
```