# Tensorflow: Getting scalar tensor value as int for pass to set_shape()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm attempting to load 3D images and their labels from a numpy array to TensorFlow records, then read them from a queue while training my network. The code for conversion is based on the conversion for TensorFlow's [Inception model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py).

Each image has a different height, width, and depth value, so when reshaping the array I need to know these values. However, I'm getting an error when I try to use set_shape, as somewhere down the line int() is being used, and it doesn't accept Tensor values.

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, value = reader.read(filename_queue)


# Features in Example proto
feature_map = {
    'height': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
    'width': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
    'depth': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
    'label': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
    'image_raw': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string)
}

features = tf.parse_single_example(value, feature_map)
result.label = tf.cast(features['label'].values[0], dtype=tf.int32)
result.height = tf.cast(features['height'].values[0], dtype=tf.int32)
result.width = tf.cast(features['width'].values[0], dtype=tf.int32)
result.depth = tf.cast(features['depth'].values[0], dtype=tf.int32)

image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'].values[0], tf.int16)

image = tf.reshape(image, [result.depth, result.height, result.width])
image = tf.cast(tf.transpose(image, [1, 2, 0]), tf.float32)
result.image = tf.expand_dims(image, 3)

result.image.set_shape([result.height, result.width, result.depth, 1])
result.label = tf.expand_dims(result.label, 0)
result.label.set_shape([1])
```

Error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dsb17_multi_gpu_train.py", line 227, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "dsb17_multi_gpu_train.py", line 223, in main
    train()
  File "dsb17_multi_gpu_train.py", line 129, in train
    loss = tower_loss(scope)
  File "dsb17_multi_gpu_train.py", line 34, in tower_loss
    images, labels = dsb17.inputs(False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dsb17/model/dsb17.py", line 104, in inputs
    batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dsb17/model/dsb17_input.py", line 161, in inputs
    read_input = read_data(filename_queue)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dsb17/model/dsb17_input.py", line 62, in read_data
    result.image.set_shape([result.height, result.width, result.depth, 1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 425, in set_shape
    self._shape = self._shape.merge_with(shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 573, in merge_with
    other = as_shape(other)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 821, in as_shape
    return TensorShape(shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 457, in __init__
    self._dims = [as_dimension(d) for d in dims_iter]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 457, in <listcomp>
    self._dims = [as_dimension(d) for d in dims_iter]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 378, in as_dimension
    return Dimension(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 33, in __init__
    self._value = int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'
```

I originally thought this was because the Tensor did not have a value until it was evaluated in a session, but loss is being evaluated in a sess.run(), which is what requires the call to tower_loss(). My training code is identical in structure to [cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py), and the overall file structure is also very similar.

The question then is: Is it actually being evaluated in a session, or is the graph not built yet? Do I need to somehow extract a value from the zero-dimensional Tensor? More generally, what am I misunderstanding about Tensors and sessions that is making my code not work as I expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

According to TensorFlow's [tf.cast docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast), tf.cast returns a Tensor.

Your error says that when using `set_shape()`, you cannot have a Tensor as an argument, but rather an int.

You may try to force Tensorflow to evaluate the cast. This simple example works for me:

```
a = tf.constant(2.0)
b = tf.constant([1.0,2.0])
b.set_shape(a.eval())
```

Without the call to `eval()`, I get the same error as you.

Comment: That was a good suggestion, but if I create a session in that section of my code (with allow_soft_placement = True, otherwise it won't work at all) followed by the .eval(), the code runs, but nothing happens. If it was working correctly, I would have gotten a message saying that images were being added to the queue, but have no idea what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot do this using [`tf.Tensor.set_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#set_shape), because that method expects a **static shape**. The tensors `result.height`, `result.width`, `result.depth` represent values read from a file, and at runtime they could evaluate to many different integers (depending on what is in your file), so there is no single `int` that you can pass for them. In that case, the best you can currently do is represent those dimensions as being statically unknown, using `None` for the unknown dimensions:

```
result.image.set_shape([None, None, None, 1])
```

Note that this statement shouldn't change anything, because TensorFlow should already be able to infer that the shape is 4-D with size 1 in the last dimension.

For more details about static and dynamic shapes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096395/3574081).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can pass the image shape to the `reshape` function but you need one more step. Just change the line:

```
image = tf.reshape(image, [result.depth, result.height, result.width])
```

to:

```
image_shape = tf.stack([result.depth, result.height, result.width])
image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)
```