# Tensorflow: static and dynamic shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes

I am having hard time due to dynamic and static shapes in tf.

I have

```
shape=tf.shape(net)
s1=tf.cast(shape[2],tf.int32)
s2=tf.cast(shape[2]/2,tf.int32)
a0=tf.random_normal([s1,s2],mean=0.,stdev=1.)
b0 = tf.get_variable(some_name, initializer=a0)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified:
```

for line b0=... .Then, I added the shape information:

```
b0 = tf.get_variable(some_name, initializer=a0,shape=[s1,s2])
```

Now I get the error:

```
If initializer is a constant, do not specify shape.
```

I realized, it has probably something to do with it being dynamic shape. So, I went back and changed to

```
shape = net.get_shape().as_list()
```

Now, I get the error:

```
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

in line corresponding to assignment of cast to s1.

I feel like I am running around in circles. How does one solve this?

I have gone through:
[How to understand static shape and dynamic shape in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096225/how-to-understand-static-shape-and-dynamic-shape-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `validate_shape=False` in the argument of `tf.get_variable`, e.g

```
init = tf.random_normal((s1, s2))
tf.get_variable(name, initializer=init, validate_shape=False)
```

Comment: I have to apply fully connected layer after some operations on this. That throws the error: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`. I think I will have to hardcode both image size and batch size for now for a temporary solution.

Comment: @edit I think you are having a new problem beyond dynamic variable shape initialization that may be worth explaining in length in a new question.