# What's the difference between the shapes in tf.shape(tensor) and print(tensor)

Tags: tensorflow, shapes

To say, i have a tensor `matrix`:

```
matrix=tf.convert_to_tensor([[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]],dtype=tf.float32)
```

and i get the shape of matrix using `tf.shape(matrix)`, the result is

```
<tf.Tensor 'Shape_2:0' shape=(2,) dtype=int32>
```

however using `print(matrix)`, i get the result:

```
<tf.Tensor 'Const_257:0' shape=(2, 4) dtype=float32>.
```

Why they are not the same.
I'm new with tensorflow, can anybody explain it?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems like you somehow messed up the formatting of your question. Anyway, I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096395/1658772) answer will answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [tf.shape()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) returns a new tensor containing the shape of the input tensor. The returned tensor is completely different than the input tensor.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> matrix = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]],dtype=tf.float32)
>>> matrix
<tf.Tensor 'Const_5:0' shape=(2, 4) dtype=float32>
>>> matrix.get_shape()
TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(4)])
>>> shape_tensor = tf.shape(matrix)
>>> shape_tensor
<tf.Tensor 'Shape_3:0' shape=(2,) dtype=int32>
```