# Confused about tensorflow variable shapes

Tags: tensorflow

I am learning tensorflow using the tensorflow machine learning cookbook  (https://github.com/nfmcclure/tensorflow_cookbook).  I am currently on the NLP chapter (07).  I am very confused about how one decides on the dimensions of the tensorflow variables.  For example, in the bag of words example they use:

```
# Create variables for logistic regression
A = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[embedding_size,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1,1]))

# Initialize placeholders
x_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[sentence_size], dtype=tf.int32)
y_target = tf.placeholder(shape=[1, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
```

and in the tf-idf example they use:

```
# Create variables for logistic regression
A = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[max_features,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1,1]))

x_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, max_features], dtype=tf.float32)
y_target = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
```

How does one decide on when to use None vs. 1 in the placeholder shapes?  Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096225/how-to-understand-static-shape-and-dynamic-shape-in-tensorflow) for an explanation of how shapes are handled in Tensorflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `None` as part of a shape, means it will be determined when you run the [session](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/client/session_management).
This is useful for training in what is called [batch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network) training where you feed each iteration of the training process a fixed size subset of the data.
So if you kept it at `None` you can switch between batch sizes without a problem. (Although you won't be doing so in the same session, but every session you can try a different batch size)

When you state a specific shape, that is what it will be and that is the only shape that can be fed to it during the session (using the `feed_dict` param)

In your specific example, the first part of code, the shape of `y_target` will always be `[1, 1]` where in the second part of code, `y_target` could be `[10, 1]` / `[200, 1]` / `[<whatever>, 1]`

Answer (score 1):

'None' should be used when count of elements in placeholder is unknown in advance. But for example in x_data placeholder if count of data elements is 1 i.e. it is known in advance, then you can replace 'None' with 1.