# Getting shape of a Tensorflow placeholder

Tags: r, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to get the dimensions of a placeholder in Tensorflow. Function `tf$shape` immediately came to my mind. I had no trouble using `tf$shape` to get the shape of a placeholder with positive dimensions. However, I want my placeholder to be able to take in inputs of different sizes, so I left one dimension as `NULL`. Now, according to my understanding, when it comes to dimensions, Tensorflow treats `NULL` and `-1` equivalently. However, when I run my code, I received this error:

> W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1148] Invalid argument: Shape [-1,2] has negative dimensions

Below is a reproducible example of my code:

```
a = tf$placeholder(tf$float32, shape = shape(NULL, 2L))    
sess = tf$Session()
sess$run(tf$shape(a))
```

Is the error cited above caused by something in my code or by the fact that `tf$shape` cannot take in a placeholder with negative dimensions? If the latter is true, is there any way for me to get the shape of a placeholder with negative dimensions without using `tf$shape`?

Answer (score 1):

The `tf$shape(a)` operation returns a tensor that contains the [*dynamic* shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096395/3574081) of placeholder tensor `a`. The dynamic shape of `a` depends on the value that you feed for `a`; if you do not feed a value, then the dynamic shape is undefined. Therefore, you must feed a value for `a` in the `sess$run(tf$shape(a))` call.

Unfortunately the particular error you are seeing ("Shape [-1,2] has negative dimensions") is unhelpful, because of a bug in TensorFlow 1.2 regarding how the placeholder op handles partially defined shapes. If you upgrade to TensorFlow 1.3 (currently available as a release candidate) or later, this bug has been fixed, and you would get an error along the lines of:

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float32 and shape [?,2]