# Why Tensor.get_shape() can work immediately before initializing the session?

Tags: tensorflow

As indicating in many TF docs, the graph begin to build only when we create the sess and execute the sess.run() method.

Just now, I tested that:

```
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[100,28,28,1])
W = tf.get_variable(...)
Y = tf.matmul(X,W)
print(Y.get_shape()[0].value)
```

As see in this code, it outputs the particular the shape value of Y even I did not t create the session instance.

How to understand? Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to calculate the matrix multiplication to determine the shape of the result probably would be one of the reasons. For instance a 3X2 tensor times a 2X5 matrix will always end up with a 3X5 matrix, you can predetermine this without the actual calculation.

Comment: Just an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's "static shape" and "dynamic shape", `get_shape()` is static and only needs graph, `tf.shape` is dynamic and needs session -- [How to understand static shape and dynamic shape in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096225/how-to-understand-static-shape-and-dynamic-shape-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Thank you very much and Now I fully understood the shape method.