# Keras input shape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

What does input shape mean in keras?

For instance, I am sending an input of shape (1 x 1440)-> 1 row and 1440 columns(features) to the keras model. There are totally 70,000 such vectors.

But When I query the model for output shape from this layer,

```
for layer in model.layers:
  if layer.name == 'input2':
     print layer.output
```

Output:

```
Tensor("input2_6:0", shape=(?, 1440), dtype=float32)
```

It says `shape=(?, 1440)`. What does this mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this question, it has some references on how shapes work in Tensorflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096225/how-to-understand-static-shape-and-dynamic-shape-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `(?,)` means that the model expects an arbitrary number of `1 x 1440` vectors. One generally does not what to fix the number of inputs to the model to some certain number.

Comment: So if my understanding is correct, the first element(?) points to the batch size and the second element refers to the number of features. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. The first element is the number of examples, so `?` means any number of examples being passed to the model.