# How to get the dynamic shape of tensors in a while_loop?

Tags: tensorflow

It's not allowed to fetch the values of tensors created inside a conditional or while loop in tensorflow. I've tried `tf.shape(t)` `Session.run()` and `Tensor.eval()`, but all of them occur errors.

Is it possible to get the shape of tensor, which is determined after graph execution?

For example, here is a while_loop:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,32,32))
i = tf.placeholder(dtype='int32')

def loop_body(i,inputs):
    x = tf.add(i, 1, name = 'add1')   
    y = tf.add(inputs,1)
    return x,y
output = tf.while_loop(lambda i,inputs: tf.less(i, 10), loop_body, [i,inputs])
```

How can I get the shape of tensor `while/add1:0` after input placeholder is feed?

Comment: The [`tf.shape()` operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096395/3574081) is the proper way to get the dynamic shape of a tensor. Please share the code and what error you were seeing when you tried that.