# Tensorflow: How to use dataset from generator in Estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Trying to build simple model just to figure out how to deal with `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`. I can not understand how to set `output_shapes` argument. I tried several combinations including not specifying it but still receive some errors due to shape mismatch of the tensors. The idea is just to yield two numpy arrays with `SIZE = 10` and run linear regression with them. Here is the code:

```
SIZE = 10


def _generator():
    feats = np.random.normal(0, 1, SIZE)
    labels = np.random.normal(0, 1, SIZE)
    yield feats, labels


def input_func_gen():
    shapes = (SIZE, SIZE)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=_generator,
                                             output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
                                             output_shapes=shapes)
    dataset = dataset.batch(10)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(20)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features_tensors, labels = iterator.get_next()
    features = {'x': features_tensors}
    return features, labels


def train():
    x_col = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='x', )
    es = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[x_col])
    es = es.train(input_fn=input_func_gen)
```

Another question is if it is possible to use this functionality to provide data for feature columns which are `tf.feature_column.crossed_column`? The overall goal is to use `Dataset.from_generator` functionality in batch training where data is loaded on chunks from a database in cases when data does not fit in memory. All opinions and examples are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The optional `output_shapes` argument of [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) allows you to specify the shapes of the values yielded from your generator. There are two constraints on its type that define how it should be specified:

- The `output_shapes` argument is a "nested structure" (e.g. a tuple, a tuple of tuples, a dict of tuples, etc.) that must match the structure of the value(s) yielded by your generator.

  In your program, `_generator()` contains the statement `yield feats, labels`. Therefore the "nested structure" is a tuple of two elements (one for each array).
- Each component of the `output_shapes` structure should match the shape of the corresponding tensor. The shape of an array is always a *tuple* of dimensions. (The shape of a `tf.Tensor` is more general: see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37096225/3574081) for a discussion.) Let's look at the actual shape of `feats`:

  ```
  >>> SIZE = 10
  >>> feats = np.random.normal(0, 1, SIZE)
  >>> print feats.shape
  (10,)
  ```

Therefore the `output_shapes` argument should be a 2-element tuple, where each element is `(SIZE,)`:

```
shapes = ((SIZE,), (SIZE,))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=_generator,
                                         output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
                                         output_shapes=shapes)
```

Finally, you will need to provide a little more information about shapes to the [`tf.feature_column.numeric_column()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/numeric_column) and [`tf.estimator.LinearRegressor()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearRegressor) APIs:

```
x_col = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='x', shape=(SIZE,))
es = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[x_col],
                                  label_dimension=10)
```

Comment: Great!! but how do you do it if your feats has a size like this: feats = np.random.rand(4,2) and labels = np.random.rand(4,1). I mean, Could I feed to the estimator with this dimension and which configure should it have. thanks @mrry

Comment: If I try do it I have this error:  ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 3 for 'linear/head/labels/assert_equal/Equal' (op: 'Equal') with input shapes: [2], [3].

Comment: @JulioCamPlaz I met the same problem, have you solved if feats has size? thx

Comment: @crafet yes, you cannot do it this way. You only can play with the batch size to get it goes faster

Comment: @crafet yes, you cannot do it this way. You only can play with the batch size to get it goes faster

Comment: @JulioCamPlaz if generator yield only one item, how to make it faster?thanks

Comment: @crafet I changed the batch size and it goes faster

Comment: @JulioCamPlaz thanks for reply. following your suggestion, it works now. still one question, there is no way to yield more than one sample using from_generator, right? at least to me, it  tried many ways but failed.