# Tensor shapes (None,) & (?,) mean?

Tags: keras, tensorboard

I am new to deep learning and tensorflow and keras. I have a question on tensor shape. What does the tensor (None,) and (?,) actually refer to the explicit shape?

Thanks

Comment: See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/37096225/712995