# How to define a variable with the same shape of a tensor in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I want to define my own loss function in keras , and the `bce_loss` multiply with a varible `W` . Actually, `W` has the same shape with the tensor `bce_loss`.

If I print the tensor `bce_loss`, maybe it can be shown as follow:

```
Tensor("loss_8/activation_14_loss/logistic_loss:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Now I don't know how to get the shape of `bce_loss`, and make the varible `W` has the the same of `bce_loss`.

My code:

```
def myLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    bce_loss = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    # want to get a variable W with the same shape of bce_loss
    # And W is initialized with normal distribution.
    val = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, size= bce_loss.size()) 
    W = keras.variable( val )
    return K.mean(self.W*bce_loss, axis = -1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your loss function like this:

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

def myLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    bce_loss = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    w = K.random_normal(K.shape(bce_loss), 0, 0.05)
    return K.mean(w * bce_loss, axis=-1)

y_t = K.placeholder((1,2))
y_p = K.placeholder((1,2))
loss = myLoss(y_t, y_p)
print(K.get_session().run(loss, {y_t: np.array([[1,1]]), y_p: np.array([[0.5, 0.2]])}))
```

Comment: How to solve this error: `ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?, 3)` by using `bce_loss.shape` ?

Comment: Sorry, K.shape should be used to get the shape. I updated the answer.

Comment: Static vs dynamic shape: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096225/how-to-understand-static-shape-and-dynamic-shape-in-tensorflow