# Tensor dimension becomes None after using gather or boolean_mask in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

For some reason I am getting different tensor dimensions when using `gather` in TF 2:

1. The first dimension becomes `None` when I use tensor as an index vector
2. The first dimension becomes `len(indices)` (as it should) where 'indices' are regular Python list

**This happens only in eager mode (e.g., inside a custom loss function)**

(Same happens when using `boolean_mask`)

**EDIT:  The following code reproduces the problem with TF 2.7.0 and Python 3.8.10**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

def cutsom_gan_loss_env(model):
   def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):

    ff = tf.where([True, True, False , False])[:, 0]
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
         tf.print(tf.gather(y_true, [0, 1], axis=0).shape)
         tf.print(tf.gather(y_true, ff, axis=0).shape)
         tape.watch(y_true)
         yy = model(y_true)
         d_yy = tape.gradient(yy,y_true)
         des_loss = tf.reduce_mean(d_yy)

    return des_loss

return custom_loss


def main_():
   n_hidden_units = 5
   num_lay = 3
   kernel_init = keras.initializers.RandomUniform(-0.1, 0.1)
   (x_train, y_train), _ = mnist.load_data()
   x_train = tf.cast(x_train,tf.float32)/255.
   inputs = Input(x_train.shape[1:])
   x = Dense(n_hidden_units,kernel_initializer=kernel_init,  activation='sigmoid' )(inputs)
   for _ in range(num_lay):
       x = Dense(n_hidden_units,kernel_initializer=kernel_init, activation='sigmoid', )(x)

   outputs =Reshape(x_train.shape[1:])(Dense(x_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer=kernel_init, activation='softmax')(x))
   model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
   model.summary()
   optimizer1 = keras.optimizers.Adam(beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=True)
   model.compile(loss=cutsom_gan_loss_env(model), optimizer=optimizer1, metrics=None)
   model.fit(x_train,  x_train , batch_size=1000, epochs=1, shuffle=False)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main_()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior with Python 3.9.7 and TF 2.7.0, which versions are you using?

Comment: @MatiasAgelvis I am using Python 3.8.10 and TF 2.5.0

Comment: @MatiasAgelvis the code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hclivLJ1Z31YJ4eGiOXXj8fD1sA2U2wF/view?usp=sharing
reproduces the problem with Python 3.8.10 and TF 2.7.0 . DO you see something else in different version?

Comment: Running your code I got the same result as you in my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error, but rather the difference between `tensor.shape` and `tf.shape`. The latter will give you the dynamic shape of a tensor after an operation like `tf.gather`.

Change:

```
tf.print(tf.gather(y_true, [0, 1], axis=0).shape)
tf.print(tf.gather(y_true, ff, axis=0).shape)
```

To:

```
tf.print(tf.shape(tf.gather(y_true, [0, 1], axis=0)))
tf.print(tf.shape(tf.gather(y_true, ff, axis=0)))
```

And the tensors will be evaluated correctly during `model.fit` using `tf.shape`. Also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096225/how-to-understand-static-shape-and-dynamic-shape-in-tensorflow) for a better understanding.