# Tensorflow tf.rank() does not return the expected value

Tags: python, tensorflow

The TF documentation says that running these two lines

```
t = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]])
tf.rank(t)
```

should return 3, as the tensor rank is 3. However, it returns

```
<tf.Tensor 'Rank_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>
```

The documentation also says the rank function is equivalent to numpy's ndim so I ran it over the given array and it does return 3.

Is there any reason for this problem?
I am using the integrated Ipython console in Spyder; python 3.5

Comment: Just noticed calling t.shape returns a shape of (2,2,3). The commands are not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I did not understand the inner workings of TensorFlow yet.
As I had read, tf.Tensors do not have values assigned to them. They are merely graphs to be computed later on. What I did not know is that they are computed only after a tf.Session() call. Running the session to calculate the rank did yield the correct "3"

The answer was found in the following question
[tf.rank function in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195549/tf-rank-function-in-tensorflow?rq=1)

Comment: You may be interested in TensorFlow's [eager execution](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/g3doc/guide.md), which will run operations immediately and make the `Tensor` objects contain concrete values.

Comment: Tensors are outputs of **nodes** in a graph and not a graph!