# how to explain the output of tf.rank in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new in tensorflow and have a question about tf.rank method.

In the doc https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/rank there is a simple example about the tf.rank:

```
# shape of tensor 't' is [2, 2, 3]
t = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]])
tf.rank(t)  # 3
```

But when I run the code below:

```
t = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]])
print(tf.rank(t))  # 3
```

I get output like:

```
Tensor("Rank:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Why can I get the output of "3"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tf.rank function in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195549/tf-rank-function-in-tensorflow)

Comment: `tf.rank(t)` creates a tensor that evaluates the rank. Using the python `print` function does not tell you the value of this tensor. You have to `sess.run()` to evaluate its value.

Comment: I would suggest to create a TF node `rank = tf.rank(t)` and evaluate this node by running a Session.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments of this question, `tf.rank(t)` creates a tensor in charge of evaluating the rank of tensor `t`. If you use the python `print()` function, it just prints information about the tensor itself.

Let's assign the `tf.rank(t)` tensor to a variable `rank` (as suggested by @Picnix_) and evaluate its value under a `tf.Session()`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]])
rank = tf.rank(t)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    rank_value = sess.run(rank)
    print(rank_value)  # Outputs --> 3
```

So, `rank_value` is the variable containing the value of tensor `rank`, and as documentation suggest its value is 3. Hope this puts some light on how tensorflow works.