# tf.get_variable returns a variable that doesn't match the given shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    weights = tf.get_variable(
        name="weights",
        shape=[9, 3, 1, 64],
        dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer()
    ),
    print(tf.shape(weights, name="weights_shape"))
```

Output:

```
Tensor("weights_shape:0", shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
```

Can't figure out why the shape of "weights" does not match the given shape.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085430/tf-shape-get-wrong-shape-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god!

found that this mystic error is just occurred by adding an extra "," after `tf.get_variable()`

But I am still curious why?

Comment: adding a comma at the end of an expression is short-hand for creating a tuple, e.g. `a=3,` results in `a` being a tuple, so `a=3,` is equivalent to `a=(3,)` or `a=tuple(3)`.