# Why can tf.random.truncated_normal get a shape that is not a vector even though it says it only receives shape of a vector?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

I am working with TensorFlow in Python.

I read through the documentation of 
[tf.random.truncated_normal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/truncated_normal)
that the input 'shape' gets 1-D tensor or python array, i.e. a vector (according to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensors).

However, with the example I'm using, 'shape' is a 4-D tensor. Or is it considered a vector? Perhaps I have problem with the definition of vectors and tensors?

```
def weight_variable(shape, name = 'noname'):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial, name = name)

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 3, 32], 'W_conv1')
```

Comment: I'm dumb, 'shape' itself is a 1-D tensor, but that does not mean the output tensor is a vector.

Comment: Have a look at this answer and the related blog post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085430/tf-shape-get-wrong-shape-in-tensorflow/37085824#37085824

Answer (score 1):

So there is a small mistake you are making in your understanding of a Tensor. A Tensor can have different "ranks". A single scalar such as 1 is a Rank 0 Tensor. A list/vector such as [1,2,3,4] is a Rank 1 Tensor. a 2-D Matrix such as [[0,0],[0,0]] is a Rank 2 Tensor and 3D Matrix are Rank 3 Tensors and so on. So the input you have here is a vector or Rank 1 Tensor not a 4-D Tensor.

[Here is a nice blog post about this.](https://www.gsrikar.com/2017/06/what-is-tensor-rank-and-tensor-shape.html)