# tensor.get_shape() vs gen_array_ops.shape(tensor) in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

What is the difference between calling `tensor.get_shape()` vs using `gen_array_ops.shape(tensor)` on a tensor?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34082273/6824418