# How to concat N tensors? N is decided in run time

Tags: tensorflow

What I want to do

```
M = tf.concat([tensor]*N, axix = 0)
```

But now, N is a tensor that decided in run time.

```
other_tensor = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, 2])
N = tf.shape(other_tensor)[0] # N is None, and it is decided in run time.
```

So, how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile), not concat. To get the shape, use [tensor.get_shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43960046/1090562) Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = tf.constant([1, 2])
c = tf.tile(a, (1, int(a.get_shape()[0])))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(c)
```

If you need your tensor to have a slightly different shape, read about the second parameter in tile function and also use `tf.reshape`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I didn't make myself clear. In my situation, a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, 2])

Comment: @ZehaoShi looking at your previous question, the answer is 'no, it was not clear at all'. To answer your followup question, go to the get_shape link and see what to do in case of dynamic shape

Comment: I use tf.shape() to get the dynamic shape. tf.tile() is exactly what I want. Thanks you very much. I'm now rewriting the question for the convenience of others.